# Вычисление суммы квадратов чисел

Tags: python

Вычислить сумму квадратов чисел от 1 до 30. Квадраты чисел записаны в файле.

В 3 части проблема

Нужно:

1. открыть файл
2. читать файл
3. каждый квадрат числа прибавить к сумме
4. закрыть файл

   ```
    f=open('text1.txt','r')
    st = f.read()
    S=0
    for str1 in f:
          for i in range(1,30)
               S=S+i
          print("S=",S)
    f.close()
   ```

Comment: Ну был же сегодня уже этот вопрос и там даже начали что-то объяснять...

Comment: @MBo: к сожалению объяснения не было

Comment: Почитайте в справке или в любом учебнике, что делает метод `read` у файлов

Comment: И там же почитайте, что пытаться читать файл, открытый на запись — плохая идея

Comment: У вас сильно разнятся две вещи: постановка задачи (которая крайне неточна) и приведенный код. Вам квадраты чего суммировать надо? Чисел из файла? Тогда почему в коде for i in range(1,30)? Если просто числе от 1 до 30, то при чем здесь вообще файл...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open('text1.txt', 'r')
S = 0
for str1 in f:
    S = S + int(str1)
print("S =", S)
f.close()
```

Как вы видите, я вполне исключил строку

```
st = f.read()
```

так как переменную `st` в дальнейшем уже никогда не употребляете, и строку

```
    for i in range(1,30)
```

так как

```
for str1 in f:
```

достаточно (читает всякую строку из входного файла).

Дальше я использовал функциу `int()` для перевода каждой строки из вводного файла на число, и наконец перенес комманду

```
print("S =", S)
```

бне цикла `for` (уничтожением отступа), чтобы он выполнился только один раз, после всех вычислений.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('text1.txt','w') as f: #открываете файл для ЗАПИСИ
    S = 0
    for i in range(1,30):
        S += i**2 #суммируете квадраты
    print(str(S))
```

Зачем вам читать и тем более ЧТО читать из файла совершенно не понятно.